# How can I wait to load elements for testing single page applications using Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium

I want to test a single page application using Selenium and Java language, how can I set a time for the test to load the elements, considering that the number of elements is large and I don't want the program to slow down?
And how to implement PAGE OBJECT MODEL(POM) in SINGLE PAGE APPLICATIONS?

Comment: Try looking at [How to get Selenium to wait for a page to load](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/selenium-wait-for-page-to-load) and [How to apply page object pattern to SPA?](https://softwaretestingboard.com/q2a/1449/how-to-apply-page-object-pattern-to-spa)

Comment: Thank you, for the pom of this page, it says to use the iframes of the page under test, but my page has only one frame, now I don't know exactly how to implement the pom?! I have to give a series of inputs, such as sign up, and when I fill in all the items, an output is created on the left side of the same page, which says that the desired object has been created, and a series of options are created to edit and delete it.